# Errno 13 - Permission denied from Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, mnist

I am trying to import downloaded MNIST data to Jupyter Notebook, but when I try to run the code, it says that it doesn't have permissions.

How do I solve the problem?

```
pip install python-mnist


from mnist import MNIST

mndata = MNIST('C:\\Users\\username\\path\\to\\the\\samples')

images, labels = mndata.load_training()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1df33381d649> in <module>
      3 mndata = MNIST('C:\\Users\\username\\path\\to\\the\\samples')
      4 
----> 5 images, labels = mndata.load_training()

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mnist\loader.py in load_training(self)
    124     def load_training(self):
    125         ims, labels = self.load(os.path.join(self.path, self.train_img_fname),
--> 126                                 os.path.join(self.path, self.train_lbl_fname))
    127 
    128         self.train_images = self.process_images(ims)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mnist\loader.py in load(self, path_img, path_lbl, batch)
    245                                  '(start_point, batch_size)')
    246 
--> 247         with self.opener(path_lbl, 'rb') as file:
    248             magic, size = struct.unpack(">II", file.read(8))
    249             if magic != 2049:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mnist\loader.py in opener(self, path_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    237             return gzip.open(path_fn + '.gz', *args, **kwargs)
    238         else:
--> 239             return open(path_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    240 
    241     def load(self, path_img, path_lbl, batch=None):

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\path\\to\\the\\samples\\train-labels-idx1-ubyte'
```

Comment: Sounds silly, but do you have the csv file open? That often happens to me.